# Loading CPP functions into Python using Ctypes

Tags: ctypes

I have a question to Ctypes and do not know what I do wrong. And yes, I am a newbie for Python and searched the other posts in here. So any advice is appreciated.

What do I want to do :

I simply want to load the FXCM C++ APP fundtions into Python 3.3 so I can call them for connecting to their server. 
As it seems Ctypes seems to be the best tool. So a simple code in Python :

```
import os
dirlist = os.listdir('ForexConnectAPIx64/bin')
from pprint import pprint
pprint(dirlist)


from ctypes import  *
myDll = cdll.LoadLibrary ("ForexConnectAPIx64/bin/ForexConnect.dll")
```

gives a result :

```
Traceback (most recent call  File "C:\Users\scaberia3\Python_Projects      \FTC\ListDir_Test.py", line 20, in <module>
myDll = cdll.LoadLibrary ("ForexConnectAPIx64/bin/ForexConnect.dll")
File "C:\Python33\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 431, in LoadLibrary
return self._dlltype(name)
File "C:\Python33\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden  (Module not found)

['ForexConnect.dll',
'fxmsg.dll',
'gsexpat.dll',
'gslibeay32.dll',
'gsssleay32.dll',
'gstool2.dll',
'gszlib.dll',
'java',
'log4cplus.dll',
'msvcp80.dll',
'msvcr80.dll',
'net',
'pdas.dll']
```

Means the path is correct ForextConnect.dll is present and I might do some very simple wrong, but have no clue what.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use Dependency Walker to figure out the correct sequence to manually load the DLLs, or simply add the directory to the system search path:

```
dllpath = os.path.abspath('ForexConnectAPIx64/bin')
os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + dllpath
myDLL = CDLL('ForexConnect.dll')
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried both, still problem in loading. The DLL is unknown.

Comment: If you've added the directory that has all of the DLLs to the system `PATH` and you still get a load error, (1) make sure you're using 64-bit Python and, if so, (2) examine the DLL with x64 Dependency Walker to see which DLL dependencies can't be found.